# How to show social share icon below product on category page in magento

Tags: extensions, magento-1, category-products, social-buttons

Hi i am trying to an extension which has the facility of showing social share button below every product on category page and single product page.

Here is the code of my extension `app\code\local\Companysocial\Mymodule\etc\config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Companysocial_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Companysocial_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Companysocial_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Companysocial_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is the code for my `app\code\local\Companysocial\Mymodule\controllers\IndexController.php` :

```
<?php
class Companysocial_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

Here is the code of my `app\code\local\Companysocial\Mymodule\Block\Mymodule.php` :

```
    <?php

class Companysocial_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
            $productImage = $product->getImageUrl(); ?>

            <a href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>">Google Plus</a>

            <a href="javascript:popWin('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'facebook', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Facebook') ?>">Facebook</a>

            <a href="javascript:popWin('http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php echo urlencode($productName . ' (' . $productUrl . ')'); ?>', 'twitter', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Tweet') ?>">Twitter</a>

            <a href="javascript:popWin('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($productImage); ?>&description=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'pinterest', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Pin it') ?>">Pinterest</a>

            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have added

```
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

This In my layout file `mymodule.xml`

But code is not shown on product page so I tried another method In `app\design\frontend\[custom_theme]\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml` :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/mymodule')->setTemplate('mymodule/mymodule.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This code works but It will show all the social share for all the product below one single product

Then after It I try to kept the social button code I wrote in function `myfunction()` in `Mymodule.php` so after it only one product link will be showing below all the product

I have searched about on and find that I have to either override the Event or observer or custom block of magento . But as it is my first plugin so I dont have any idea about it 
So Please give me the solution How can I override or add my social share button in below product on category page

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement,you need to `some modification` at  ***module.phtml and Mymodule.php***.

Instead of loading all product  at **myfunction()**  and you `need to send product Object`   to call from  `list.phtml and product/view.phtml`.

Like:  `setProduct($project)`.

> ```
> <?php
> class Companysocial_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
> {
>  protected $_product = null;
>
>     public function setProduct($product) {
>         $this->_product = $product;
>         return $this;
>     }
>
>     public function myfunction() {
>         return $this->_product;
>     }
> ```

}

**Then add below code at  module.phtml:**

```
 $product=$this->myfunction()
$sku = $product->getSku();
$productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
$productImage = $product->getImageUrl(); ?>

<a href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>">Google Plus</a>

<a href="javascript:popWin('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'facebook', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Facebook') ?>">Facebook</a>

<a href="javascript:popWin('http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php echo urlencode($productName . ' (' . $productUrl . ')'); ?>', 'twitter', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Tweet') ?>">Twitter</a>

<a href="javascript:popWin('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($productImage); ?>&description=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'pinterest', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Pin it') ?>">Pinterest</a>
```

### Let call this code at list.phtml.

> ```
>     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/mymodule')
> ->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('mymodule/mymodule.phtml')->toHtml();
> ```
>
> ?>

You need to call this code below each product in list.phtml

### Also you can call share block using below code:

> ```
> <?php echo
> $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/mymodule')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('mymodule/mymodule.phtml')->toHtml();
>  ?>
> ```

***Note that*** in my process you `does not need mymodule.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create module for this.

Simply create a `local.xml` file in `theme/layout` folder and have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>catalog/product/list_new.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>catalog/product/list_new.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Then copy all content from `thme/template/catalog/product/list_new.phtml` and paste in to your new file `theme/template/catalog/product/list_new.phtml`.

Now, add this line inside `<li>` tag in `list_new.phtml` file:

```
<div class="social-share">
  <?php 
     $sku = $_product->getSku();
     $productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
     $productImage = $_product->getImageUrl();
  ?>
  <a href="javascript:popWin('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'google', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Google Plus') ?>">Google Plus</a>

  <a href="javascript:popWin('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'facebook', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Facebook') ?>">Facebook</a>

  <a href="javascript:popWin('http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php echo urlencode($productName . ' (' . $productUrl . ')'); ?>', 'twitter', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Tweet') ?>">Twitter</a>

  <a href="javascript:popWin('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($productImage); ?>&description=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'pinterest', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Pin it') ?>">Pinterest</a>
</div>
```

Remember this `<div>` should be inside `<li> (foreach)`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this code put in catalog/product/view/addto.phtml

```
<?php 
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        ?>
        <ul class="add-to-links">
            <li>
                <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1141295062596906";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
                <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>

                <!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                  })();
                </script>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-hashtags="VoidCanvas">Tweet</a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-save="true" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"></a>
                <script async defer src="https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code in .phtml file.

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="social-media-icons">
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl());?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName())?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on facebook">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/facebook-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Facebook" width="5%">
</a>
<!-- Pinterest -->
<a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl()); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getImageUrl());?> &description=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName()); ?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Pin it">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/pinterest-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Pinterest" width="5%">
</a>
<!-- Google Plus -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl()); ?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on Google Plus">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/googleplus-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Google Plus" width="5%">
</a>
</div>
```